# In what situation do I need to extend a class?

Tags: java, class, extend

I'm learning java and was wondering in what situation you would want to extend a class like here is suggested:

http://5upcodes.blogspot.fi/2013/08/java-inheritance.html

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call that a tutorial. In fact, I wouldn't even say it's much of an example...

Comment: Read [FAQ]. And to answer: usually in a quiet workplace, with colleagues around, nothing fancy.

Comment: I know this question is on topic... But I feel you may get more interesting answers in either [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or  [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com). Both are sister sites of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite example of inheritance is the shapes example.  All squares are shapes, but not all shapes are squares.

Assume you have a class called "shape".  All shapes have perimeter, area etc.  These would be the data members of your shapes class.

lets say you wanted to create a class called circle.  circle could extend your shape class, so that it would still have the data members of the shape class, and you could add elements that are specific to the circle, such as a radius. (a square wouldn't have a radius).

The circle class would be said to "inherit" from the shape class, because it has all of the features of a shape, and also new features specific only to the circle class.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to create a class that is generally similar to the super class(the class being extended), you extend it and customize it. Overwriting some of it's functions, and/or add functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "is-a" scenario, one of the three OOP pillars (inheritance, encapsulation, polymorphism). If you have a class Animal, then you may want to extend a Dog class from Animal. A dog is an animal, but not the other way around. All animals have cells, but dogs have other features aside from that. That'd be a pretty basic idea of it.

Answer (score 2):

The OOP good practice is to `program towards interfaces`. But in some cases you can take advantage using inheritance: for example, when your top class has a well-defined behavior (i mean concrete code), which all the child classes will inherit - this reduces code, complexity and give you a better maintenance scenario.

In the other hand, if your model is too abstract (the basic behavior is not very clear), then you should think about using interfaces.

And if you're creating real-life software, don't forget *design patterns* - someone may already solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

For simple reason we extend one class two another and the funda is called as INHERITANCE.

Say,if you want to create a program in which there are two vehicle class i.e.- Car and Boat, which has similar properties except some.

```
public class Vehicle
{
  void engine()
}

protected class Car extends Vehicle
{
 void tyres()
}

protected class Boat extends Vehicle
{
 void propeller()
}
```

You see both vehicle has engines but has different modes as one moves with the help of tyres and another with propeller.

So, two avoid re-writing code of method engine, we inherited it in sub-classes.
Hope, this will help ya !

Answer (score 1):

Extending class is one of basics of OOP, along with interfaces. Lets say, you have general class called Building. It has members like area, city where building is (or coordinates) etc.

Now, with extend, you can specify house to "Cottage", "SkyScraper" etc. They will have functionality of parent + something more (eg. number of levels for SkyScaraper).

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason to use inheritance is to extend behavior of the base class.

For instance, if you're making a video game you might have a `Character` class that contains all the code needed for a character to navigate the world and do whatever else they do.

You could then extend `Character` with `Player` and `NPC`, so that `Player` (representing the player character) contains the logic that allows the person playing the game to control their character, and `NPC` (representing a Non-Player-Character) contains the logic allowing the computer to control the other characters. This way, all of the logic core to every character is encapsulated in the `Character` class, and the subclasses only have the logic needed to extend specific behavior.

For example, the `Character` class might have a method for movement.

```
protected void MoveToLocation(x, y)
{
 //movement logic goes here
}
```

And then the `Player` class might contain a mouselistener to move the player to wherever is clicked.

```
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent mouseEvent)
{
    MoveToLocation(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
}
```

And `NPC` will figure it out on its own somehow

```
protected void decideWhereToGo()
{
    int destinationX, destinationY;
    //logic for determining destination
    MoveToLocation(destinationX, destinationY);
}
```

Because they both inherit from `Character` they both know how to `MoveToLocation`, and if you ever want to change how that is done you only have to modify the code in one place and every `Character` (whether they are a `Player` or `NPC` they are still a `Character` by way of inheritence) will have the updated behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class, you have a parent-child relation between the original one and the new, extending one.

The child class, the one extending the parent class, will have each and every member of the parent class, without the need to declare them again. Even the private members, though you won't be able to access them directly.

You extend a class when you want the new class to have all the same features of the original, and something more. The child class may then either add new functionalities, or override some funcionalities of the parent class.

You may also use extension when you want to have a set of classes that are related and share some common functionality, but with different implementation when it comes to the details. For example, usually for graphical interfaces you have a `Control` class, which has functionalities related to rendering and positioning. Then you have its children called `Button`, `Textbox`, `Combo` etc. All have some implementation in common, but each is different in their details.

Make sure to study about interfaces, too. Sometimes you want a lot of related classes so that they have a common set of members, but no shared functionality. In cases like that, it may be better to implement an interface than to extend a common class. An interface is like a class, but with no implementation in it (it serves only to tell you which members its implementors should have).

Answer (score 0):

Generally extending a class is so that you are creating class based on something. For example, in order to create an activity, you must extend Activity. If your class is to setup a IntentService, then you must extend your class to use IntentService.

```
public class AClassNameHere extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

public class ClassName extends IntentService{
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the superclass to Override super class method to be specific to sub class
example:

In case your superclass is a generic class with generic behaviour, eg Animal class can be a generic class like

```
class Animal{
private String name;
public String getVoice(){
return "Animal";
}
```

}

Now you need to create say a class Cat which is of Type Animal but with different voice then you just extend the superclass Animal and just override the getVoice() method
like

```
class Cat extends Animal{

public String getVoice(){
return "mew";
}   
}
```

Now if you have code like this:
Animal cat= new Cat();
cat.getVoice();//it will return "mew"

Practically this you can use in number of situations like
1. Extending an existing framework class to your custom class.
2. If you are developing any framework you can expose some classes which you want the user to customize.

But overriding introduces IS-A relationship.

Answer (score -1):

There are three major drawbacks with inheritance. Even though the relationship is an "is a" relationship, consider these three while deciding to inheriting a class.

1. Partial inheritance is not possible. You can't extend partially.
2. It is statically linked. Inheritance relationship is static. You can't change that relationship at runtime.
3. You can't restrict the behavior through inheritance. (That is possible in C++ through private inheritance. But not in java )

Comment: I think, while considering the reason for inheritance, one will have to consider its drawbacks also.

Comment: Yes, but the question was *why*, and you answered with *you're going to suffer if you use that*. Hardly an answer at all.

Comment: @Renan, So you mean to say that, one doesn't need to consider if there are any issues if he decides extend one class? I strongly feel that if i'm writing Properties class and wouldn't have extend Properties class from Hashtable if i would have thought about "is anyone going to suffer if i extend Properties from Hashtable"

Comment: You may consider the issues if you so wish - it actually enriches the discussion - but that does not answer the question. You should address the actual point to make it an answer. Do check the answers that got upvoted - they all explain what the purpose of inheritance is, and when it should be applied. Some of them do go around points that are accessory to the OP's question. But they all get to the point in the end.

Comment: @Renan, I don't agree with you, The question was about the "situations" on which one will extend the class. "situations" include positive and negative situations. Otherwise people would have gone for inheritance for almost all kinds of "is a" relationship.

Comment: Let's try an analogy. If you ask me *"when should I use lemons in a sauce"*, and I say *"lemons are sour"*, have I answered your question?

Comment: @Renan, If that is the case, there will be only one or two answer to any questions. For that no one needs to ask questions here. They can simply search in google and get a "well defined" answer.

Answer (score -2):

Almost never. It's best only to extend classes that have been actively designed for it. Most class implementors give no thought to what will happen if people extend their classes. There are all manner of issues.

Composition is your best friend.

Vulnerabilities include

- you can no longer correctly implement equals() or hashCode() in subclasses
- you are violating encapsulation, and now rely on the internals of another class
- you are vulnerable to changes in the parent class
- you are required to accept any new methods that get added to the parent class
- you must worry about the Liskov Substitution Principle, which can lead to subtle bugs

Josh Bloch, in his excellent book Effective Java, 2nd Edition, talks about this in several places, including items 8, 16 and 17.

Comment: This sounds a lot like "I don't like allen wrenches, so let's vow to never use allen wrenches."

Comment: Bad answer. Inheritance is there for a reason.

Comment: That's a radical answer, but i has a point: avoid inheritance if a interface will solve your problems. Inheritance raises the complexity and can get messy very quickly.

Comment: @Renan I think you're missing the very important qualifier 'Almost'.

Comment: @Mehrdad All of the language features are there for a reason. That doesn't mean they should be used inappropriately. Extension of instantiable classes is trouble unless you're careful and know what you're doing.

Comment: @EricStein I didn't miss it. Let me make another analogy. Imagine you asked me how do airbags work, and I told you "don't drive - you're going to crash your car and die". Would that be a satisfactory answer for you?

Comment: @Renan That analogy is invalid. He asked "when". I answered "when". I didn't say "go program in C#".

Comment: @EricStein No you didn't. He asked "in what situation", and you said "Almost never, do this instead, because if you do extend you're going to mess things up". But you didn't explain when he **should** extend. That is tangential at best.

Comment: @EricStein: Inheritance is *not* one of those features that should be used sparingly. It's like the steering wheel in a car. You obviously need to use it correctly but saying you should almost never use it is plain wrong.

Comment: @Mehrdad Would you, perhaps, care to dispute any of the specific issues I raised? "You're wrong!" isn't very convincing to me.

Comment: @Renan "It's best to only extend classes that have been actively designed for it." If you like, I can edit the reply to explain how to design a class for extension. That seems tangental to me, though.

Comment: Yes, I dispute the phrase "almost never".

Comment: So you agree with all of the issues I raised, and you still think it's a great idea to extend all the time?